# SKLearn LinearSVC.Coef_/GridSearchCV._best_estimator_coef_

Tags: python, svm

I am using the coef_ method to recover feature weights from LinearSVC for a binary classification problem. It looks like the weights recovered are for the negative class. Can someone confirm whether this is true?